# Editing navigation from site Actions results in error in MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, security, navigation

When I or any other user on any machine tries to change the navigation through Site Actions - Modify Navigation, an error occurs stating

> "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your
>   web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."

This error occurs throughout the farm and has only been noticed since we applied the June CUs last week. I don't think this error occurred prior to this, though can't be sure as changing the navigation doesn't occur frequently.

I have however, been able to make an urgent change using the object model through Powershell directly on the MOSS server.

The ULS has an entry below

```
Process: w3wp.exe  
TID: 0x0FDC  
Area: Windows SharePoint Services  
Category: General  
EventID: 8kh7  
Level: High 
Message: (Error as recorded above)
```

I can't find any recurring messages surrounding this entry.

Comment: Hi Mike, may I ask what would you like to ask? Base on the information above, I can see your observation and findings but could not find any question. May I assume that you wish to ask what caused the error?